# Reading a iCal file only gets most recent event?

Tags: calendar, icalendar

I have an ics file which is generated by a project I am doing, and it validates in http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/. When I try to import it into KOrganizer or Maya it only loads the most recent event however. For example, the ics file is:

```
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
    PRODID:-//K Desktop Environment//NONSGML libkcal 4.3//EN
    VERSION:2.0
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTAMP:20130504T094939Z
    CREATED:20130503T230000Z
    LAST-MODIFIED:20130504T094939Z
    SUMMARY:Cat
    DTSTART:20130504T000000
    DTEND:20130504T010000
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTAMP:20130504T094939Z
    CREATED:20130503T230000Z
    LAST-MODIFIED:20130504T094939Z
    SUMMARY:Foo
    DTSTART:20130504T000000
    DTEND:20130504T010000
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTAMP:20130504T094939Z
    CREATED:20130503T230000Z
    LAST-MODIFIED:20130504T094939Z
    SUMMARY:Dog
    DTSTART:20130504T000000
    DTEND:20130504T010000
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR
```

It will read it in, but only display the first event. It also changes the ics file to

```
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    PRODID:-//K Desktop Environment//NONSGML libkcal 4.3//EN
    VERSION:2.0
    X-KDE-ICAL-IMPLEMENTATION-VERSION:1.0
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTAMP:20130504T094939Z
    CREATED:20130504T094939Z
    LAST-MODIFIED:20130504T094939Z
    SUMMARY:Cat
    DTSTART:20130504T000000
    DTEND:20130504T010000
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR
```

Does anyone know if it is my ics file which is at fault, or Kontact?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, every event must have a unique `UID` property..